# Discrete math sets help?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would I do this question?

suppose U = {1,2...,9}, A= all multiples of 2, B = all multiples of 3, and C = {3,4,5,6,7}. Find C-(B - A).

I really don't know how I would approach this question so can anybody help with this?

Comment: Can you at least find $B\setminus A$?

Comment: so would it be a={2,4,6,8,10} and b={3,6,9,12,15}

Comment: $10$ isn’t in $U$, so it can’t be in $A$. Similarly, $12$ and $15$ aren’t in $U$ and therefore can’t be in $B$.

Comment: would the answer be nine?

Comment: The final answer? No, definitely not, since $9$ isn’t even in $C$.

Comment: sorry its 4,5,6,7 right?

Comment: Yes, it is: the only element of $C$ that is also in $\{3,9\}$ is $3$, so it’s the only one that gets removed when we take the set difference $C\setminus\{3,9\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiples of $3$ in $U$ are $3,6$, and $9$, so $B=\{3,6,9\}$. The multiples of $2$ in $U$ are $2,4,6$, and $8$, so $A=\{2,4,6,8\}$. For any sets $X$ and $Y$, the set difference $X\setminus Y$ is the set of objects that are in $X$ but not $Y$. Thus, $B\setminus A$ is the set of digits that are in $B$ but not in $A$. Look at the members of $B$: $3$ and $9$ are in $B$ but not $A$, so they’re in $B\setminus A$. $6$, on the other hand, is in $B$ **and** $A$, so it’s not in $B\setminus A$. And nothing else is in $B$, never mind whether it’s in $A$ or not, so nothing else is in $B\setminus A$. Thus, $B\setminus A=\{3,9\}$.

Now see if you can apply the same sort of reasoning to find $C\setminus\{3,9\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $B$ is the set of multiples of $3$ in the universe, then the elements of $B$ are just $3, 6, 9$; that is,

$$B = \{3, 6, 9\}$$

---

Likewise, $A$ is the set of even numbers inside $U$, so $A = \{2, 4, 6, 8\}$. Then $B - A$ is the set of things in $B$ that aren't in $A$. We see that $3$ and $9$ are in $B$ not in $A$, so

$$B - A = \{3, 9\}$$

Answer (score 0):

C-(B-A). If we want to substract something to C then we should first know what we want to substract to it.

B-A is essentially the elements in B that are not in A. the multiples of 3 in the universe are {3,6,9}=B and the multiples of 2 are {2,4,6,8}=A. so the multiples that are exclusive to B are {3,9}.

Ok so know we want to find the elements in C not in {3,9}. These are {4,5,6,7}